My loadall function works but my line by line loadEmployeeData function is not working for one function but not an other?
So loadAllEmployeeData works but for some reason and renders correctly in my webpage but the loadEMployeeData one just does nothing...I think it may have to do with the const employeeDbArray?
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    renderAlphabetLinks();
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    myTime();
});

function renderAlphabetLinks() {
    const alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    const container = document.getElementById('alphabetLinks');
    let html = '';
    for (let letter of alphabet) {
        html += `<a href="#" onclick="loadEmployeeData('${letter}')">${letter}</a> `;
    }
    html += `<a href="#" onclick="loadAllEmployeeData()">ALL</a>`;
    container.innerHTML = html;
}

async function loadEmployeeData(letter) {  
    try {
        const response = await fetch('/employees');
        const data = await response.text();
        const employeeDbArray = data.split("\n").filter(name => name.toUpperCase().startsWith(letter));
        const targetDiv = document.getElementById('employeeList');
        targetDiv.innerHTML = employeeDbArray.join('<br>');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching employee data:', error);
    }
}

async function loadAllEmployeeData() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('/employees');
        const data = await response.text();
        const targetDiv = document.getElementById('employeeList');
        targetDiv.innerHTML = data.split("\n").join('<br>');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching all employee data:', error);
    }
}


}


Are there any errors in your console? What steps have you taken to debug it?

The files you are fetching don't exist here; you should create a minimal reproducible example to replicate the problem.

No errors when I inspect in the browser, as you can see both functions are nearly identical with the only difference being "const employeeDbArray = data.split("\n").filter(name => name.toUpperCase().startsWith(letter));" If i click on a letter and not "ALL" in my ui under network -> fetch -> preview it shows me the correct JSON which tells me that clicking the letter buttons initiates the fetch request correctly and that it just does not know what to do with them?

What do you get when you log data, data.split("\n"), etc?

Oh this fixed it "const response = await fetch('/employees');
const employees = await response.json(); // Assuming the server sends back JSON
console.log("All Employees:", employees); // Debugging
    // Filter employees based on the letter
    const filteredEmployees = employees.filter(employee => {
        // Assuming employee data structure has a name field at index 1
        const name = employee[1] || ""; // Fallback to empty string if undefined
        return name.toUpperCase().startsWith(letter.toUpperCase());"


If you have a solution you should post it as an Answer below, not in a comment.

async function loadEmployeeData(letter) {
try {
    const response = await fetch('/employees');
    const employees = await response.json(); // Assuming the server sends back JSON

    // Filter employees based on the letter
    const filteredEmployees = employees.filter(employee => {
        const name = employee[1] || ""; // Assuming [ID, Name, ...]
        return name.toUpperCase().startsWith(letter.toUpperCase());
    });

    // Utilize the common rendering function
    renderEmployees(filteredEmployees);
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching employee data:', error);
}

}
Works fine :)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
